# how to save a history point for a gridview in updatepanel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, asp.net-ajax

I have a form which displays the data as per the search filters. Filters are few textboxes which allows the user to find the desired data.

Search button is the trigger for the update panel which contains Listview and the data is displayed as per the selected filters.Listview rows has a edit button. when i try to edit some record and come back by clicking the browser back button i dont find the List view anymore.

Is there a way wherein i can save the history point so that the Listview could be cashed and viewed quickly when i come back.

After few search i understood that scriptmanager enable history is set to true and history point is set.

But how to save the gridview data and display it back?

Can anyone help me out with this. Any example will help.

Comment: are you using any menthod for filling gridview data?

Comment: No what i am asking is the data coming from Db and you are binding to the Gridview right ? are you doinf this in any method ?